# Download Songs off Zune

Tags: macos, media, zune

I have a super old Zune player with a bunch of my music loaded on it. Is it possible to download the content of the Zune to my computer (it's a Mac)? I see posts about an app called Windows Phone, but it looks like it just syncs to the Zune.

Anyway to mount the contents of Zune as a hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Phone 7 Connector](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20993) works with the Zune player. You can sync music and other non-DRM media to and from your Mac.

Comment: If I try downloading from that URL, it gives me a text file with another URL which then directs me into the App Store and says "This is not available for download in the US". Hmmm...